# Здравствуйте, я создал бота крестики нолики на python в telegram, при нажатии на кнопки ( ничья, выигрыш) каждое сообщение бота дублируется

Tags: python, telegram, telebot

```py
def make_board(end=False, draw=False, symbol='x'):
    if end:
        keyboard = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=3)
        if draw:
            txt = 'Конец! Ничья!'
        else:
            txt = f'Конец! Победил игрок , который играл за "{symbol[1]}"
```

Comment: задай понятный вопрос как разумный человек, а не набор букв, как школьник.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: похоже тут не помешают и скрины бота в телеграме и не стоит пихать весь вопрос в заголовок, тем более `Здравствуйте`)